# Javascript - Loading icon in SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, time

I have a loop that has a set timeout variable. How can I make a loading icon while it is counting down, then possibly have a bit of code that will stop it spinning (or just showing). I was thinking jquery rotate might do the trick, but im not keen of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/ seems to be pretty well done if you don't mind using a bit of JavaScript. Another possibility is a GIF which you just manually show and hide, which you can generate with something like http://ajaxload.info/.

Answer (score 1):

```
function imgload(){
setTimeout(function(){$('#response').html('<img src="imagse/load.gif">');  },2000);
}


the load image rotates for 2 seconds..
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work without any plugins, but it assumes you know how long the process will take from the point where you start showing the loading image to the point where you wish to stop showing the loading image.

```
var countdown = 5000;  // your countdown in milliseconds

setTimeout(function() {
    // hide your loading image after "countdown" milliseconds
    document.getElementById("loading-image").setAttribute("style","display:none");

}, countdown);

// show your loading image
document.getElementById("loading-image").setAttribute("style","display:block");


<img style="display:none" src="/loading.gif" id="loading-image" alt="Loading..." />
```

Of course, if you want the loading image to stop based on some other event, you can simply hide the image in that particular callback method using:

```
document.getElementById("loading-image").setAttribute("style","display:none");
```

Now that you have this answer, I do encourage you to revisit your stance on plug-ins. The best engineers in any field build on top of the platforms that came before them. When you stand on the shoulders of giants, there is a lot you can accomplish very quickly.

Comment: Sweeet. Thanks. I can't belive I couldn't find this on Google. Quite simple when you read it.

Comment: Since you are using `jQuery`, you can simply use `$('#loading-image').hide()` and `$('#loading-image').show()` instead of setting the css attributes.